# List get values by clause where

Tags: c#, list

How can I add clause *where* for get not all values ?

```
        var response = proxy.GetInformation(
            new TravelAgencyService.Messages.TravelAgencyRequest()
            {
                Accommodation = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
            });
        List<string> kindOfAccommodation = response.Offers
        .Select(o => o.RodzajZakwaterowania )
        .Distinct()
        //.Where()??
        .OrderBy(c => c)
        .ToList();
```

User must select country from comboBox and after that I want to choose only kind of accommodation in this country and fetch in next comboBox

Comment: try using it like this List<string> kindOfAccommodation = response.Offers..Where()
        .Select(o => o.RodzajZakwaterowania )
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(c => c)
        .ToList();

Comment: What do you want to filter on? You gotta give us a bit more information. What does the Offers object look like for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var response = proxy.GetInformation(
        new TravelAgencyService.Messages.TravelAgencyRequest()
        {
            Accommodation = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        });
    List<string> kindOfAccommodation = response.Offers
    .Where(offer => offer.AttributeOfOffer == valueToFilter)
    .Select(o => o.RodzajZakwaterowania )        
    .Distinct()       
    .OrderBy(c => c)
        .ToList();
```